# Is there a possibility to group properties using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, properties, configuration, config, configuration-files

Can something like this be accomplished using Spring Boot? 
[image]

The idea is to group properties and assign the same value to all of them, so instead of all of the properties ending with 'test*' i would like to change just one property 'my.flag'. I know that such functionality works in case of loggers, but can I define my own group?

Comment: You can implement this by yourself without writing much code, by creating custom getters that use the "override" when it's not `null` or the actual value when it is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether your problem has been solved or not, but I want to provide a solution to achieve what you want  by using `spring.factories` and implementing `ApplicationListener` as following steps.

**STEP 1**
Create a class `MyPropertiesListener` which implements `ApplicationListener` and read the value of `my.flag` in `application.properties` first, then set it to all the properties whose key starts with `my.flag.`.

```
public class MyPropertiesListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = event.getEnvironment();
        String myFlag = env.getProperty("my.flag");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        MutablePropertySources propSrcs = env.getPropertySources();
        StreamSupport.stream(propSrcs.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(ps -> ps instanceof EnumerablePropertySource)
        .map(ps -> ((MapPropertySource) ps).getPropertyNames())
        .flatMap(Arrays::<String>stream)
        .forEach(propName -> {
            if (propName.toString().startsWith("my.flag.")) {
                props.put(propName, myFlag);
            }
        });

        env.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("myProps", props));
    }
}
```

**STEP 2**
Create a file named `spring.factories` under `src/main/resource/META-INF` and configure `MyPropertiesListener` into it.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=xxx.xxx.xxx.MyPropertiesListener
```

**TEST**
The value of `my.flag.test3` is `false` in `application.properties` originally, but it is going to be overwritten as `true` while application starts.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Value("${my.flag.test3}")
    private String test3;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(test3); //true
    }
}
```

---

**See also**
[Creating a Custom Starter with Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter)